# Eyes And Teeth Going Haywire With Rigify Rig And MakeHuman Model

Tags: rigify, makehuman

hope all is going well for you!

I'm having an issue where the eyes and teeth of a MakeHuman model do not quite work properly with a Rigify rig.
[image: issue]

Simply put, I have no idea how to fix this.
If anyone can provide some insight concerning this, I would greatly appreciate it.
Also if anyone needs to poke around in the blend file itself, [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42126) is a link.

If any other details are needed, just let me know!

Thanks, and take care. =-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the *head bone* in ***Pose Mode***, then your mesh with <kbd>RMB</kbd> and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode* (check the ***Show Weights*** in *Display* panel of the *Properties Shelf* [<kbd>N</kbd>] to see the weights), mark the head vertices (with <kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd>), then go to *Object Data* header and ***assign*** the ***1.000*** weight to the head's vertex group.
[image]

To solve the issue with eyebrows and eyes select the *neck bone* in ***Pose Mode*** and correct the weight values for each one.
[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed response! It's much appreciated. I am curious, though, about those dark bits under the eyes upon rotation. Is this just a graphical issue?

Comment: I guess I haven't assigned the right value for the eyes. Maybe you should try 1.800 or 2.200. You have to experiment a bit :).

Comment: After some experimenting, I've found that the issue is not with the eyes, so you did just fine there. =-)

[image](http://s33.postimg.org/mwbezduun/sockets.png)

After looking at the mesh a bit more, I've found that it's more the inner eye sockets coming through the lower part of the outer eye sockets than the eyes themselves.

As you said, I need to experiment a bit with the weighting, but that's definitely what's going on.

Edit: Initially I found and fixed this with the neck, but it's also the case with the head, lowering the weight of the sockets on both bones works wonderfully!