# Problem with rigging (the eyes and eyelashes don't follow the head)

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, armature

I'm making an anime model. When I go to *Pose Mode* and try to rotate the head the eyes don't follow it well. The eyelashes change position and the eyes pop out of where they should be. I have painted the whole head red in the *weight paint mode*. Should I paint the eyes in a different way?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. This site is English only, so could you please try to translate your question, or it will most certainly be closed or deleted. And don't worry if your English isn't perfect; a lot of people here, myself included, have a native language other than English, and it works well most of the time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not written in English language as per site rules

Comment: For what is worth you should also probably post your weight paint screenshot as well as an image showing the issue.

Comment: The only words I could understand here was *'weight paint'* :). Thank you google translator! Here are the analogical issues as yours IMO: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76715/while-moving-arm-leg-mesh-messes-up and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63381/mesh-doest-move-with-armature

Comment: The eyes and eyelashes probably share the weights that don't belong to the head/neck bones. You have to select every single bone of the rig and make sure they haven't got any weight influence on eyes and eyelashes (remove the weights from them as in example links above).